# How does git calculate line changes?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a file with only one line of text in it, I commit my file and then I add one more line to it, now my file looks like this:

1. Line one
2. Line two

I commit my file again and here is what I got:

```
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Why are there 2 insertions and 1 deletion?
I think it's just 1 insertion and 0 deletion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 2 insertions and 1 deletion because the existing line was changed (probably by adding a newline at the end) - which is 1 delete and 1 insert because there is no "changed" - and then an additional line was also added.  Do a git diff and it will show this.

Comment: I'm still quite vague. Can you share document write about this, please?

Comment: @YoungCyborg : more details on "Do a git diff" : from your current commit, in a terminal, run `git diff HEAD^ HEAD -- path/to/file`, or `git show`

Comment: @YoungCyborg: A line is everything up to *and including* the final newline. If the last "line" of a file is missing a newline, and you add a new last line, you've changed the *previous* line to add a newline. The command-line diff will tell you that there is a missing newline at the end of the file (in the old file; possibly also in the new file, which will set you up to make this happen again *next time*). GitHub diffs tell you the same thing but do so with a tiny little symbol that is easy to miss.